# Creating a grid view banner responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been inspired by website sliders however since i did not need a slider i've tried to create it static. However i'm struggling with some issues. First of all when you hover the big column the text hides? how come it does that? Secondly i'm struggling to make it responsive. i want the columns to be under eachother when you make the browser smaller and make the height proportional to the full width? How can i achieve this?

```
<head>

<style>
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;

}

.item {
    float: left;

}

.double-size {
    width: 66.6666%;
    height: auto;




}

.normal-size {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3333%;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;



}

.double-size .column-big {
    box-sizing:border-box; 
   width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px 2px 0px 0px;





}

.normal-size .column-small-1 {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;  
    padding: 0px 0px 2px 2px;





}

.normal-size .column-small-2 {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;

    padding: 2px 0px 0px 2px;

}

.column-content {

    height: 100%;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;


}



.column-content .meta-info-doub {
box-sizing:border-box;
position: absolute;
height: auto;
width: 100%;
bottom:0;
right: 0;
padding: 40px;
}

.column-content .meta-info-norm {
box-sizing:border-box;
position: absolute;
height: auto;
width: 100%;
bottom:0;
right: 0;
padding: 20px;
}



 .title-double {

    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 1.65;
background: #161616;
background: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
color: #fff;
display: inline;
padding: 4px 0;
margin: 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: 7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5), -7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
box-shadow: 7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5), -7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
text-transform: uppercase;


}

 .title-normal {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
line-height: 1.65;
background: #161616;
background: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
color: #fff;
display: inline;
padding: 4px 0;
margin: 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: 7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5), -7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
box-shadow: 7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5), -7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
text-transform: uppercase;


}

 .date-double {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    display: inline;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #222;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
    display: block;
}


 .date-normal {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    display: inline;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #222;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
    display: block;
}



.column-content .content-image{

    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; 
    background-size: 100%; 
    display:block; 
     -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;

}

.column-content .content-image:hover {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);  

}

@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
    .normal-size {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 3px;

    }
    .double-size {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;

    }
}

</style>
</head>


<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item double-size">
        <div class="column-big">
            <div class="column-content">

                    <div class="meta-info-doub">
                        <h3 class="date-double">23. Oktober 2015</h3>
                        <h3 class="title-double">Post 1</h3>



                    </div>

                <span href="#" id="img-zoom" class="content-image" style="background-image:url(http://blognewswp.gotheme.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/shutterstock_190029455_supersize-640x400.jpg)"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item normal-size">
        <div class="column-small-1">
            <div class="column-content">
                <a href="#" class="content-image" style="background-image:url(http://blognewswp.gotheme.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/shutterstock_190029455_supersize-640x400.jpg )"></a>

                    <div class="meta-info-norm">
                        <h3 class="date-double">23. Oktober 2015</h3>
                        <div class="info-title"><h3 class="title-normal">Post 2</h3></div>



                    </div>




            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column-small-2">
            <div class="column-content">
                <a href="#" class="content-image" style="background-image:url(http://blognewswp.gotheme.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/shutterstock_190029455_supersize-640x400.jpg)"></a>

                    <div class="meta-info-norm">
                        <h3 class="date-double">23. Oktober 2015</h3>
                        <div class="info-title"><h3 class="title-normal">Post 3</h3></div>



                    </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



</div>




</body>
```

Comment: I really tried to render this but was unable, you should not use span tags for background images, use div instead. And not pass background-image inline, put it in style tags in header. Can you point to same example?

Comment: First of all thank you for your time. You can just change the span or a tags to div tags and it will work still. here is the example that im trying to recreate http://motive.theme-sphere.com/news-demo/ (without the sldier functionality). However for responsive reason i just want them to stack on the eachother when the browser is less than 768.

Comment: Well generally that is done by floating elements(probably on the left) on higher widths and then remove float on lower widths. That was div will stack one after another, as they are in normal flow of document. I mean if you don't float block elements they will stack one after another.

Comment: You have any idea why the text is hiding? in the big column? on mouse over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `<div class="column-content">` move span tag to the top, before any other divs

```
<div class="column-content">
  <span href="#" id="img-zoom" class="content-image" style="background-  image:url(http://blognewswp.gotheme.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/shutterstock_190029455_supersize-640x400.jpg)"></span>
  <div class="meta-info-doub">
  <h3 class="date-double">23. Oktober 2015</h3>
  <h3 class="title-double">Post 1</h3>
</div>
```

Like you did in other two post divs.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, interactively changing the layout of a page is not possible in pure CSS. Therefore, to move the panels below each other you'd have to use JavaScript, listen to a `window.onresize` event like this:

```
window.onresize = function(event)
{
    // check the width of the window and move the panels accordingly
}
```

As for the text that gets hidden, that is because you transform the image to move closer to the screen. You have to think of your canvas like a 3D space, and you don't actually make the image bigger, but move it closer to the viewer, so now the text is just behind the image. To easily fix this, set `z-index: 1;` on `.meta-info-doub`.

I also tried finding a "clean" fix for this that produces the exact same result, but that does not seem to be possible, at least not using `background-size` and `background-position`, `zoom` or replacing the `span` tag with a `div` and putting the image as `img` tag inside it and fiddling with `width`, `height`, `margin` and `padding`.